# I am Try To Add <tr> Table Is Empty</tr> using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

If table is empty then table display table is empty if data are there then is display it.

Code Link are There

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vpobp1k/#&togetherjs=EaL1Q7fwDr)

```js
$(document).ready(function()
 { 
 
  
 
  $("#price,#t_pro").blur(function () {

   $('#total_price').val($('#price').val() * $('#t_pro').val());

  });
  $("#order").click(function(){ 
   
   var shop_name = $("#s_name").val();
   var pro_name = $("#product_names").val();
   var email = $("#emailid").val();
   var mobi = $("#mobileno").val();
   var ur = $('input[name="are"]').val();
   var pric = $("#price").val();
   var total_pro = $("#t_pro").val();
   var total_pri = $("#total_price").val();
   
   var cnt;
   //var a=$('#mytab').empty();
   if(cnt=0)
   {     
       var newRow = $("<tr><td>No Record found</td></tr>");
       $("#mytab").append(newRow);
       cnt--;

   } 
   else 
   {
     $("#mytab").append('<tr><td>'+ shop_name +'</td><td>'+ pro_name
       +'</td><td>'+ email +'</td><td>'+ mobi
       +'</td><td>'+ ur +'</td><td>'+ pric +'</td><td>'+ total_pro +'</td><td>'+ total_pri +'</td><td><button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button></td><td><button type="button" class="edit" >Edit</button></td></tr>');
      cnt++;
   }
   return cnt;
  
  });
  
  
  /*function Edit()
  {
   var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr 
   var shop_name = par.children("td:nth-child(1)"); 
   var pro_name = par.children("td:nth-child(2)"); 
   var email = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
   var mobi = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
   var ur = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");
   var pric = par.children("td:nth-child(6)");
   var total_pro = par.children("td:nth-child(7)");
   var total_pri = par.children("td:nth-child(8)");
   
   var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)"); 
   shop_name.html("<input type='text' id='s_name' size='30' class='txt' value='"+shop_name.html()+"'/>"); 
   pro_name.html("<select id='product_names' class='product_name'><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>select..</option><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>PC</option><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>Laptop</option><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>Mobile Phone</option><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>Plagma Screen</option></select>"); 
   email.html("<input type='text' id='emailid' size='30' value='"+email.html()+"'/>");
   mobi.html("<input type='text' id='mobileno' size='30' class='txt' value='"+mobi.html()+"'/>");
   ur.html("<input type='radio' name='are' value='"+ur.html()+"' size='10'>Buyer<input type='radio' name='are' value='"+ur.html()+"' size='10'>Seller");
   pric.html("<input type='text' id='price' size='30' class='txt' value='"+pric.html+"'/>");
   total_pro.html("<input type='text' id='t_pro' size='30' class='txt' value='"+total_pro.html+"'/>");
   total_pri.html("<input type='text' id='total_price' size='30' class='txt' value='"+total_pri.html+"'/>");
   
    
   
   $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
   $(".edit").bind("click", Edit); 
   $(".delete").bind("click", Delete); 
  };
  function Save()
  { 
   var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr 
   var shop_name = par.children("td:nth-child(1)"); 
   var pro_name = par.children("td:nth-child(2)"); 
   var email = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
   var mobi = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
   var ur = par.children("td:nth-child(5)");
   var pric = par.children("td:nth-child(6)");
   var total_pro = par.children("td:nth-child(7)");
   var total_pri = par.children("td:nth-child(8)");
   
   var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)"); 
   shop_name.html("<input type='text' id='s_name' size='30' class='txt' value='"+shop_name.html()+"'/>"); 
   pro_name.html("<select id='product_names' class='product_name'><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>select..</option><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>PC</option><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>Laptop</option><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>Mobile Phone</option><option value='"+pro_name.html+"'>Plagma Screen</option></select>"); 
   email.html("<input type='text' id='emailid' size='30' value='"+email.html()+"'/>");
   mobi.html("<input type='text' id='mobileno' size='30' class='txt' value='"+mobi.html()+"'>");
   ur.html("<input type='radio' name='are' value='"+ur.html()+"' size='10'>Buyer<input type='radio' name='are' value='"+ur.html()+"' size='10'>Seller");
   pric.html("<input type='text' id='price' size='30' class='txt' value='"+pric.html+"'>");
   total_pro.html("<input type='text' id='t_pro' size='30' class='txt' value='"+total_pro.html+"'>");
   total_pri.html("<input type='text' id='total_price' size='30' class='txt' value='"+total_pri.html+"'>");
   
    
   
   $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
   $(".edit").bind("click", Edit); 
   $(".delete").bind("click", Delete); 
  }; */



  
  $(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
   var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
   par.remove();
  });
  
 });
```

```css
input.txt {
  color: #00008B;
  background-color: #E3F2F7;
  border: 1px inset #00008B;
  width: 200px;
}
input.btn {
  color: #00008B;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  border: 1px outset #00008B;
}
form div {
  clear: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 0.9em;
}
form div label {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  font: bold 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>




</head>
<body>
<form>

<table cellpadding="2" width="20%"  align="center" cellspacing="2">

 <tr>
 <td colspan=2>
 <center><font size=4><b>Product Detail Form</b></font></center>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Shop Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="s_name" size="30" class="txt"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Product Name</td>
 <td><select id="product_names" class="product_name">
 <option value="-1" selected>select..</option>
 <option value="pc">PC</option>
 <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
 <option value="mobile_phone">Mobile Phone</option>
 <option value="plagma_screen">Plagma Screen</option>
 </select></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>EmailId</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="emailid" size="30" class="txt"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>MobileNo</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="mobileno" size="30" class="txt"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>What You Are</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="are" value="Buyer" size="10">Buyer
 <input type="radio" name="are" value="Seller" size="10">Seller</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Price</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="price" size="30" class="txt"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Total Product</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="t_pro" size="30" class="txt"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Total Price</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="total_price" size="30" class="txt"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><input type="reset" class="btn"></td>
 <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="order" value="Order" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>

<table cellpadding="4" width="40%"  align="center" cellspacing="4" id="mytab" border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>ShopNmae</th>
  <th>Product Name</th>
  <th>EmailId</th>
  <th>MobileNo</th>
  <th>What You Are</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Total Product</th>
  <th>Total Price</th>
  <th>Action</th>
 </tr>
 
 
 
</table>

<script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 
 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Changes in your fiddle and working]In your fiddle change `var cnt;` to `var cnt = 0;`

Also change if condition to

```
if(cnt==0)
{     
    var newRow = $("<tr><td colspan='9'>No Record found</td></tr>");
    $("#mytab").append(newRow);
    cnt--;
}
```

**Note** you are not assigning any value to cnt variable please check that

Hope this helps you

Comment: please can you sent in gmail parmar.dhimesh7@gmail.com

Comment: what do you want me to send

Comment: gmail email id please

Comment: parmar.dhimesh7@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you Rohit Shah sir

Comment: sir now i am tried to click on edit button then table is disappear and in document i can perform editing with update button. any idea how to perform this task